# Delete Issue with MVC 5 List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Recently taken some time away from MVC and come back to an old project, trying to re-write code I've done previously but have come unstuck whilst deleting an item from a list, with EF it's fine but I'm trying not to use Entity Framework to manage my model data. I want to use my model as a database until I'm happy to submit.

I've re-written the issue to simplify it and not dump loads of code, when clicking delete I'm getting the below error:

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult RemoveRequested(Int32)' in 'Project.Views.requestedController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters*

I think that the id is usually handled by EF but I thought `[key]` would handle this to auto-increment - is this possible to sort?

Hope this makes sense. Dynamic I don't really care about, so ideally no jQuery/java script unless I have to.

**Code:**

**Partial View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Allocation>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var ri in Model)
        {
            <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <span>
                        @ri.one
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <span>
                        @ri.two
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <span>
                        @ri.three
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <span>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "RemoveRequested", new { id = ri.id })
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

**Models**

```
public class Allocation
    {
        [Key]
        public int? id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string one { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string two { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string three { get; set; }
    }
public class Container
{
    [key]
    public int? id { get;set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Allocation> requested { get;set; }
}
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
public ActionResult RemoveRequested(int id)
        {
            var newContainer = (Container)Session["containerSession"];
            if(newAllocation.requested != null)
            {
                var del = newContainer.requested.Find(m => m.id == id);
                newContainer.requested.Remove(del);
            }
            Session["containerSession"] = newContainer;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not have a nullable key and add the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute.

Change your `Allocation` type change it to:

```
public class Allocation
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string one { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string two { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string three { get; set; }
}
```

This will match your action parameter now.
However if your key is null you must have other issues and they will now use the default value of zero.

Another option would be to change your action to accept the nullable type as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult RemoveRequested(int? id)
```

Pls note I would also use a `HttpPost` to delete rather than an `HttpGet` as you are currently doing.

Comment: Ok - thanks, made a few changes now getting `Requested URL: /Container/RemoveRequested/0` - so the id isn't being assigned, how would be best to do this?

Comment: Add this onto your key `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` too. :)

Comment: Does this require EF? What is that doing? I want to avoid EF, so just using the model as a temporary db before a submit to the actual db.

Comment: That is EF, if it were me I would have a view model or model and use automapper to map it from an EF data entity with the EF specific attributes on it but it is all depending on your architecture choice.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful - so I can't easily achieve this without a temp db file? Just delete at the end of session/final submit?

Comment: @PurpleSmurph No probs. You could use another ORM or different method to interact with the db in a repository but there are lots of choices depending on your design. Do you need to avoid EF or something?

Comment: I want to just add and delete items from the object list. Avoiding EF because it's writing loads of code I don't know what it's doing, simple to do with EF - but I want to be able to write something without it - sorry convoluted but hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @PurpleSmurph It sounds like you want to write the ground-level stuff. You could use a command to do so https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823.aspx or use something like Dapper. They feel like you have more control. Might be worth asking another question as others will suggest more probably.

Comment: @PurpleSmurph No problem. :)